# PHP resources for the Perl Programmer

Tags: php, perl

I used to write PHP 10 years ago.  For the last few years I've been much more into the C variant languages and Perl.  Any recommendations for books or resources that seem particularly well geared towards the transition from Perl to PHP?

*EDIT*: It turns out this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/429558/8817), I just didn't see it in my search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are good references for Perl programmers who want to learn PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429558/what-are-good-references-for-perl-programmers-who-want-to-learn-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I learn a new language, I try to pretend that I don't know other languages so I can learn the new one on its own terms. Don't try to write Perl or C in PHP. Get back into PHP without all the baggage of what you already know.

There is already an answer for [What are good references for Perl programmers who want to learn PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/429558/8817), too.

Answer (score 3):

Really, the [PHP online documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) won't ever let you down.  If you have a vague idea of what kind of function you need, you can [search for it](https://www.php.net/search.php?show=quickref&lang=en&).  Just take a stab at the function name and it'll return results that are similar.  Once you find the function you're looking for, it'll give you code examples, related functions, and all sorts of goodies (along with lots of user comments!).

(When I got my start with PHP, I didn't use any books for resources because of the abundance of sample code available from the main documentation website.)

Answer (score 0):

Following URL contains comparison of both. Hopefully will help

http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/phpvscgi.shtml

Comment: 1. It is very small 2. It wouldn't be useful for a Perl programmer - it compares with very, very old Perl style.